# How to determine whether computer is on Domain from event logs?

Tags: windows-xp, domain, event-log

I have spent a short period of time in an office recently, and I was able to dump the event logs on to a USB drive.

There are only XP Pro machines in the office.  Is it possible that there is a domain running?

What should I look for in the Event Logs to work out whether they are in a domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you check the Security section of the Event Viewer (or the appropriate log):
[image]

If you open an entry here, you'll see a log entry for some authentication event. The event I opened here was validated against the domain `WINXP`. That is, in fact, the name of the workstation, not a domain controller:
[image]

So this could be a hint that the whole machine is not connected to a domain. If you check more entries, you can see if there ever was an authentication event against another machine (maybe a domain controller).

I don't think this would be a reliable way to determine if a client is, in fact, a domain client. But it might help.

---

Just FYI, a quick way to determine if the machine is part of a domain **if you have access to it** could be to:

```
echo %LOGONSERVER%
```

on a command prompt. If it prints the local machine name, it's not part of a domain. Otherwise, it should print the name of the domain controller.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a search for 3260 this is the event that will show in the system log when a PC joins a domain.

[Event 3260](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-3260-source-Workstation-eventno-6956-phase-1.htm)

Comment: Is that emitted with every user logon or only when the machine **initially** joins the domain?