# How to show the recycle bin icon on the desktop in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have strange problem with the recycle bin icon on my Windows 7 system. I can't enable it in the "Desktop icon Settings" window by checking the checkbox to show it, because this option is unavailable.

[image]

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: What version of Windows 7 are you running?

Comment: Version 6.1(Build 7601:Service Pack 1)

Comment: I meant Home/Professional/Ultimate?
At least you are patched to date though.

Comment: ok it's Professional version

Comment: and all patches are installed too

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi: could you upload a screenshot somewhere, I'll add it to this post then.

Comment: yep, https://github.com/ishikawayoshi/Test/tree/master/pics

Comment: i think that this question linked to my http://superuser.com/questions/48529/how-can-i-get-to-the-recycle-bin-without-the-desktop-icon-in-windows-7 i have the same problem when i ask question

Comment: Do you use this PC on a company domain?

Comment: sorry, you ask it's company pc or not? anyway it's not a home pc it's work pc

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi Being a company PC would not automatically imply it being part of a Windows domain (but it would be likely). Please see: http://superuser.com/questions/399747/how-to-determine-whether-computer-is-on-domain-from-event-logs/399780#399780

Comment: it looks like that my pc is part of the domain echo %LOGONSERVER% says something like \\DC01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope [**This post**](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-restore-recycle-bin-in-windows-7/) will help you , please try it.

Recycle Bin option is unavailable in Desktop icons settings box, you need to enable it via Windows Registry by following the steps given below:

[image]

1. Download **[Restore Recycle Bin](http://cloud.intowindows.com/wp-content/uploads/My%20uploaded%20files/Restore%20Recycle%20Bin.reg)** Registry file.
2. Right-click on the file and then select Open.
3. Click Yes for the prompt.
   [image]
   [image]
4. Now click Ok. Reboot your machine to see Recycle Bin on your Desktop. Note that this will also enable Recycle Bin option in Desktop icon settings box.

Comment: thanks Desingh, it works great! But when i execute script it not update Windows Registry, after that i update it manualy.

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi - If it didn't update the registry for you then it didn't have permission to do so.  The script work fine on a virtual machine I tested it on.

Comment: hm, sorry i don't know why it not work first time, but i tested it now and it works fine. thnx again